# CASE statement and group by

Tags: sql

```
select  [Major Genre],count(*) as 'Movie Count', 
        sum([US Gross]) as 'Total US Gross',
        sum([Worldwide Gross]-[Production Budget]) as 'Profit', 
        (sum([Worldwide Gross]-[Production Budget])/SUM([Production Budget]))*100 as 'Gross Profit',
    case when sum([US Gross])>=200000000 AND sum([US Gross])<=999000000 
         then 'US Gross more then 220M'
         when sum([US Gross])>=999000000 
         then 'US Gross more then 999M'
     end AS 'US Gross Status'
from Sheet1$
group by [Major Genre],[US Gross]
having [US Gross] > 220000000
order by [Major Genre]
```

I want it to show only the summarize info about each Major Genre, now I getting a few row the each Major Genre
how can I fix that?

Comment: This isn't MySQL.

Answer (score 0):

It would help if you could supply sample data and desired output, however looking at your query I can see where it needs a slight tweak. You need to remove `[US Gross]` from the `Group by` and `sum` it in the `Having` clause. By grouping by it, you will be getting rows for each distinct value, despite using `sum`.

```
select [Major Genre], count(*) as 'Movie Count', 
sum([US Gross]) as 'Total US Gross',
sum([Worldwide Gross]-[Production Budget]) as 'Profit', 
(sum([Worldwide Gross]-[Production Budget])/SUM([Production Budget]))*100 as 'Gross Profit',
    case when sum([US Gross])>=200000000 AND sum([US Gross])<=999000000 
    then 'US Gross more then 220M'
    when sum([US Gross])>=999000000 
    then 'US Gross more then 999M'
    end AS 'US Gross Status'
from Sheet1$
group by [Major Genre]
having Sum([US Gross]) > 220000000
order by [Major Genre]
```